# Unable to remove event listener Javascript

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

I'm trying to remove an event handler before adding a new one. Otherwise it will fire multiple times. This is the method that gets called to attach/remove it.

```
function attachRemoveBookEvent(bookEl) {

    function remove() {
        bookEl.remove();

        for(let i=0; i < bookObjects.length; i++) {
            if(bookObjects[i].id == bookEl.getAttribute("data-id")) {
                bookObjects.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        hideContainer(removeContainer);
    }
    removeConfirm.removeEventListener("click", remove);
    removeConfirm.addEventListener("click", remove);
}
```

I'm not sure if it because the methods are actually not identical, it keeps firing multiple times when I press the button.

Comment: Do you want `removeConfirm` to only ever have one event listener at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the interpreter runs across a `function` keyword, a new function is created. So, if you call `attachRemoveBookEvent` and attach a listener, and then you call `attachRemoveBookEvent` again, you no longer have a reference to the *original* `remove` function that was created in the original call - rather, you have a reference to the *new* `remove` function that was just created. Somehow, you'll have to make sure that the function you pass in is the same as the one that `addEventListener` was called with. One possibility would be to have have a persistent reference to the current `remove` that's attached to `removeConfirm`:

```
let remove = null;
function attachRemoveBookEvent(bookEl) {
  removeConfirm.removeEventListener("click", remove);
  remove = function remove() {
    bookEl.remove();
    for(let i=0; i < bookObjects.length; i++) {
      if(bookObjects[i].id == bookEl.getAttribute("data-id")) {
        bookObjects.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    hideContainer(removeContainer);
  }
  removeConfirm.addEventListener("click", remove);
}
```

Or, depending on the sort of logic you want, you might be able to keep the event listener on *permanently*, and rather than reattaching it, only reassign the `bookEl`, in a persistent outer variable, something a bit like:

```
let currentBookEl = null;
function remove() {
  if (currentBookEl) currentBookEl.remove();
  for(let i=0; i < bookObjects.length; i++) {
    if(bookObjects[i].id == bookEl.getAttribute("data-id")) {
      bookObjects.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  hideContainer(removeContainer);
}
function attachRemoveBookEvent(bookEl) {
  currentBookEl = bookEl;
}
```

Also, rather than manually iterating over `bookObjects` and `break`ing, a better option when you're trying to find the index of an element in an array is `findIndex`:

```
const idToFind = bookEl.getAttribute("data-id");
const index = bookObjects.find(({ id }) => id === idToFind);
bookObjects.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: that did the trick, thanks and thanks also for the explanation as to why it was happening!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the element and only add the listener if the class doesn't exist

```
function attachRemoveBookEvent(bookEl) {

  function remove() {
    bookEl.remove();

    for (let i = 0; i < bookObjects.length; i++) {
      if (bookObjects[i].id == bookEl.getAttribute("data-id")) {
        bookObjects.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }

    hideContainer(removeContainer);
  }

  if(!removeConfirm.classList.contains('someClass')) {
    removeConfirm.classList.add('someClass')
    removeConfirm.addEventListener("click", remove);
  }


}
```